# Keep mobile Data always on function

Tags: android

If you go through HTC phones, they have an option for mobile data network setting to "Always enable mobile data". As I understand, it helps to maintain a TCP connection. I want to implement the same functionality, how to implement it ?
as I think, need to use wakelock?

Comment: You shouldn't need a wakelock for this.

Comment: but when this options is ON, mobile data shouldn't disconnect even after device sleep/standby mode..so there is any other option but to use wakelock to do this ?

Comment: Did you consider the implications this has on the battery life?

Comment: I know this is not good on battery..so want to know how htc actually implement this ? do they implement same ?

Answer (score 0):

WakeLocks are a Power Manager system Service feature, available to your
applications to control the power state of the host device.

Comment: when this option is OFF, mobile data disconnects automatically after device enters sleep/standby mode.

Comment: but when this options is ON, mobile data shouldn't disconnect even after device sleep/standby mode..so there is any other option but to use wakelock to do this ?

Comment: Nope, mobile data connection is always on unless the user turn it off manually.

Comment: then i dont understand why htc gave this functionality in their phones..i can only deduce this from this option

Comment: Every phone does have this option, Htc ain't no special.

Comment: no Samsung don't have this option, there are 2 different options a) Mobile data (ON/OFF) b) Always use mobile data(ON/OFF)

Comment: I do  have Samsung Galaxy Y S5360, It has under the Wireless and network settings -> Mobile networks -> Use packet data. Al most every Android phone does have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the connection (Mobile or wifi). But you can listen the connection instantly and let your application works on only mobile data.

Comment: if i listen to connection and on mobile data connected..invoke wakelock..will it ensure that mobile data doesn't disconnect while in sleep mode ?

Comment: It cant. But if you dont want your app to go sleep mod, you can use wake lock